# Scheduling multiple pipelines as a different dataflow job in a single template file

Tags: python-3.x, google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, google-cloud-dataflow, google-cloud-bigtable

I need to execute multiple pipelines in parallel(each pipeline is going to do the same logic but with different inputs) and want to get the metric count after executing the pipeline. The problem is while creating the template for the pipeline since it creates only one template file for each pipeline so it overrides the old template and finally get the template file for last pipeline alone. Basically we are doing this to get the row count fetched from Bigquery and bigtable(written rows) are same or not for different data sources.

Note: I am using multithreading to schedule the pipelines in parallel.

```
   def getrow_count(self, pipeline, metric_name):
        if not hasattr(pipeline.result, 'has_job'):
            read_filter = MetricsFilter().with_name(metric_name)
            query_result = pipeline.result.metrics().query(read_filter)
            if query_result['counters']:
                read_counter = query_result['counters'][0]
                print(f"Row count for metric {metric_name} is {read_counter.committed}")
                return read_counter.committed
            
    def run_pipeline(self, query_text, schema, table_type):
        job_name = table_type.replace('_','') + datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%Y%m%d")
        self.options.view_as(GoogleCloudOptions).job_name = str(job_name)
        self.options.view_as(GoogleCloudOptions).temp_location = 'gs://dataflow_storage_bq_bt/dataflow_test/tmp/' + table_type
        self.options.view_as(GoogleCloudOptions).staging_location = 'gs://dataflow_storage_bq_bt/dataflow_test/tmp/'+ table_type
        print(self.options.view_as(GoogleCloudOptions).staging_location)
        with beam.Pipeline(options=self.options) as pipeline:
            data_collection = pipeline | f"Get {table_type} from BigQuery" >> beam.io.Read(ReadFromBigQuery(query=query_text.get(),
                                                                                                        use_standard_sql=True))

            data_collection \
            | f"Get  {table_type} list of direct_row's " >> beam.ParDo(CreateRowFn(schema)) \
            | f"Get  {table_type} single direct row" >> beam.ParDo(GetRowFn()) \
            | f"Write  {table_type} To BT" >> WriteToBigTable(project_id=self.config_data["gcp_config"]["bt_project"],
                                                            instance_id=self.config_data["gcp_config"]["bt_instance_id"],
                                                            table_id=self.config_data["gcp_config"]["bt_table_id"])
        
        bigquery_count = self.getrow_count(pipeline,'bigquery_row') 
        bigtable_count = self.getrow_count(pipeline,'Written Row')
        if bigquery_count is None or bigtable_count is None:
            print(f"No daily upload data for {table_type}")  
        elif bigquery_count == bigtable_count:
            print(f"All daily upload data for {table_type} moved to bigtable from bigquery")
        else:
            raise ValueError("Row count mismatch; check the pipeline for {table_type}")
        
    def get_query_text(self, file_path):
        query_text_read_output = self.get_blob_data(file_path)
        query_text = query_text_read_output.decode('utf-8')
        return query_text

    def get_blob_data(self, file_path):
        blob = self.bucket.get_blob(file_path)
        data = blob.download_as_string()
        return data    

    def run(self):
        self.set_options()        
        sql_config = self.config_data["sql_config"]
        querytext1= self.options.view_as(DailyUploadOptions).test1
        querytext2= self.options.view_as(DailyUploadOptions).test2
        querytext3= self.options.view_as(DailyUploadOptions).test3
        querytext4= self.options.view_as(DailyUploadOptions).test4
        querytext5= self.options.view_as(DailyUploadOptions).test5
        querytext6= self.options.view_as(DailyUploadOptions).test6
        querytext7 = self.options.view_as(DailyUploadOptions).test7
        
        Thread(target=self.run_pipeline,
           args=(querytext1,
                 sql_config['test1_config']['schema'],
                 'feature1')).start()
        time.sleep(100) #sleep time should be there or else dataflow job will get failed due to same job name pciked in subsequent job
        Thread(target=self.run_pipeline,
           args=(querytext2,
                 sql_config['test2_config']['schema'],
                 'feature2')).start()
        time.sleep(100)
        Thread(target=self.run_pipeline,
           args=(querytext3,
                 sql_config['test3_config']['schema'],
                 'feature3')).start()
        time.sleep(100)
        Thread(target=self.run_pipeline,
           args=(querytext4,
                 sql_config['test4_config']['schema'],
                 'feature4')).start()
        time.sleep(100)
        Thread(target=self.run_pipeline,
           args=(querytext5,
                 sql_config['test5_config']['schema'],
                 'feature5')).start()
        time.sleep(100)
        Thread(target=self.run_pipeline,
           args=(querytext6,
                 sql_config['test6_config']['schema'],
                 'feature6')).start()
        time.sleep(100)
        Thread(target=self.run_pipeline,
           args=(querytext7,
                 sql_config['test7_config']['schema'],
                 'feature7')).start()
    

class CreateRowFn(beam.DoFn):
    def __init__(self, schema):
        self.schema = schema
        self.bg_count = Metrics.counter('Bigquery', 'bigquery_row')
    def process(self, key):
        self.bg_count.inc()
        direct_rows = []
        data = json.loads(key['data'], strict=False)
        direct_row = row.DirectRow(row_key=data["row_key"])
        for table_type in self.schema:
            for column_family in self.schema[table_type]['columns']:
                for column in self.schema[table_type]['columns'][column_family]:
                    direct_row.set_cell(
                        column_family,
                        column,
                        json.dumps(data.get(column, {})),
                        datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(0.0))
                    direct_rows.append(direct_row)
        return [direct_rows]


class GetRowFn(beam.DoFn):
    def process(self, row_list):
        for row in row_list:
            return [row]
```

Comment: I don't understand the problem. If you put your inputs in parameters, you can have only one template customized with the parameters, that's all

Comment: Thanks guillaume,.. i am passing the input parameters( in my case, 7 pipelines with diff parameters) inside the main function itself. as you said , i will try to pass my inputs as parameters and trigger this pipeline with diff inputs simultaneously.

Comment: do you want to run 1 dataflo with 7 jobs inside it, or 7 dataflow with only 1 job in it?

Comment: i am trying to achieve 1 dataflow with 7 jobs in a single template file, so template file should remain the same but the input paratmeters are going to be differ

Comment: I proposed code refactor of 2 of your functions. Let me know if it works, else I will delete my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Can you try this. Define the pipeline before, and then use it in parallel. In addition, don't worry about parallelism, let Dataflow managing it. You will disturb its own thread manager if you manage yourselves the thread.

```
    def run_pipeline(self, pipeline, query_text, schema, table_type):
        data_collection = pipeline | f"Get {table_type} from BigQuery" >> beam.io.Read(ReadFromBigQuery(query=query_text.get(), use_standard_sql=True))
.......
  
    def run(self):
        self.set_options()        
        sql_config = self.config_data["sql_config"]
        querytext1= self.options.view_as(DailyUploadOptions).test1
        querytext2= self.options.view_as(DailyUploadOptions).test2
        querytext3= self.options.view_as(DailyUploadOptions).test3
        querytext4= self.options.view_as(DailyUploadOptions).test4
        querytext5= self.options.view_as(DailyUploadOptions).test5
        querytext6= self.options.view_as(DailyUploadOptions).test6
        querytext7 = self.options.view_as(DailyUploadOptions).test7

        job_name = table_type.replace('_','') + datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%Y%m%d")
        self.options.view_as(GoogleCloudOptions).job_name = str(job_name)
        self.options.view_as(GoogleCloudOptions).temp_location = 'gs://dataflow_storage_bq_bt/dataflow_test/tmp/' + table_type
        self.options.view_as(GoogleCloudOptions).staging_location = 'gs://dataflow_storage_bq_bt/dataflow_test/tmp/'+ table_type
        print(self.options.view_as(GoogleCloudOptions).staging_location)
        pipeline = beam.Pipeline(options=self.options)

        
        run_pipeline(pipeline, querytext1,
                 sql_config['test1_config']['schema'],
                 'feature1')
        run_pipeline(pipeline, querytext2,
                 sql_config['test2_config']['schema'],
                 'feature2')
        run_pipeline(pipeline, querytext3,
                 sql_config['test3_config']['schema'],
                 'feature3')
        run_pipeline(pipeline, querytext4,
                 sql_config['test4_config']['schema'],
                 'feature4')
        run_pipeline(pipeline, querytext5,
                 sql_config['test5_config']['schema'],
                 'feature5')
        run_pipeline(pipeline, querytext6,
                 sql_config['test6_config']['schema'],
                 'feature6')
        run_pipeline(pipeline, querytext7,
                 sql_config['test7_config']['schema'],
                 'feature7')
        pipeline.run()
```

Comment: Thanks Guillaume. yes we have tried the above but our purpose is to we need to get the counts( read from bigquery and writes to bigtable) so that we can compare and throw error using metric name filter. or is there any other way of getting the counts( input from bigquery and writes to bigtable)? and one more thing is that we can able to get the metric counters once the pipeline got completed only and this leads to seperate job for each feature rather than all features inside a single dataflow job.

Comment: In Java, it's possible to get the output of the writer to get Pcollection of errors and OK rows. I don't know if it's also possible in Python. You can also count all element in the PCollection.

Comment: yes. I am using the custom metric counter for bigquery in pcollections and for bigtable, in the WriteToBigTable inbuilt function, i am using the counter name "written row" to get write count, but the problem is that i can able to get both the counts once the pipeline got finished and i cant able to get the counter values inside the pipeline itself.

Comment: Correct, with BigQuery, it's part of the pipeline, but with bigtable, it's at the end :( I don't know why there is this difference.